# Symfony form builder. Multiple select in array

Tags: symfony

I want to make a input which is select type. The problem it will have over 100 select options. How this can be handle with array of data ? Is it possible to include array in form builder input ?

This is the example:

```
   ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => 'Your company name',
        'choices' => [
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
            'something' => 'something',
        ]
    ])
```

You can see that there's a lot of `choices` how it would be possible to hold this data somewhere else ?

Comment: depends how you get those options, if it's flat and never change a trait like @herr Nentu' is good enougth. But you can also put this in a php file that just return an array of your values, or encapsulate this array in a Value Object (immutable :p), so many option here

Comment: Trait has to be created manually ? I cannot find any command in make or create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a trait and create an array.

```
trait SomethingTrait
{
    /** @var array */
    protected $aSomething = [
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
        'something' => 'something',
    ];
}
```

i your type form :

```
use SomethingTrait;

....

   ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, [
        'label' => 'Your company name',
        'choices' => $this->aSomething
    ])
```

Comment: Trait has to be created manually ? I cannot find any command in `make` or `create`

Comment: manually in the code: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a static array of choice, Traits are probably the best option.

But if you're getting your array of choice from the database or an other source elsewhere than in the code itself, and if this array can change according to the context, you have to use the `configureOptions` function of your FormType:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $options['allowed_titles'], //use "allowed_titles" option defined below
                'label' => 'label.title',
                'placeholder' => 'label.choose_in_list' //(if you want to add a NULL value default choice (invalid choice when submitting))
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'allowed_titles' => [], //define "allowed_titles" option and its default value
        ]);
    }

    //...
}
```

And in your Controller, init your form with your array of choice in options:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MyFormType::class, $entity, [
    'allowed_titles' => $allowedTitles
]);
```